# Python IF statement asks for input twice before proceeding

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

I am trying to code a chatbot.

I am working on a function where the user asks the chatbot how it is doing, it breaks my sentence into words and IF a keyword exists in the list, it proceeds to ask the user how they are doing.

I then use an if/elif statement, IF the user states a positive feeling, and that feeling exists in the list of positive feelings, it then should state that it is happy to hear that.

ELSE IF the user states a negative feeling, and that feeling exists in the list of negative feelings, it offers to cheer the user up with a joke.

The problem is this:
-The user asks the bot how it is doing

-The bot replies "I'm well, what about you"

-The user replies happy or sad (both are words in according happy-feeling-list and negative-feeling-list)

-The bot replies accordingly (If the user is well, it is happy, if the user isn't, it offers to say a joke)

-No matter what the user inputs afterwards, the bot loops back at the beginning and replies again "I'm well, what about you"

-ONLY If the user repeats the same steps AGAIN, then the process finally continues, with the bot either saying a joke or being happy that the user is well.

Why does this happen? I can't really figure a reason

Here is the function code:

```
def howareyou(sentence):      
for word in sentence.split():
    #IF WORD IS IN CHECK UP INPUT LIST
    if (word.lower() in HOWAREYOU_INPUTS):
        print ("BOT: " + random.choice(HOWAREYOU_RESPONSES) + " What about you?")
        #USER STATES IF THEY ARE WELL OR NOT
        secondquestion = input("YOU: ")
        for word in secondquestion.split():
            #IF USER REPLIES POSITIVELY, BOT REPLIES HAPPILY
            if (word.lower() in POSITIVE_INPUTS):
                return random.choice(ALSOHAPPY_RESPONSES)
            #IF USER REPLIES NEGATIVELY, BOT OFFERS TO SAY A JOKE
            elif (word.lower() in NEGATIVE_INPUTS):
                print ("BOT: Maybe a joke will help?")
                jokeoffer = input("YOU: ")
                jokeoffer = jokeoffer.lower()
                for word in jokeoffer.split():
                    #USER AGREES TO A JOKE
                    if (word.lower() in AGREE_INPUTS):
                        return random.choice(JOKE_LIST)
                    #USER DECLINES OFFER
                    else:
                        return random.choice(GETWELL_RESPONSES)
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is somewhere other than the code you included in your question.  I copied and pasted it into IDLE and it ran fine (after fixing the indentation error in the function - the for loop and everything after should be indented one more level)

Comment: I tested each case (happy, sad, want joke, don't want joke) and none of the cases caused the bot to go back to the beginning for me.  When I got to the joke question input, the bot responded normally for both yes and no

Comment: Maybe double check the words lists?  To test your function, I declared lists of strings for each of the inputs and responses lists your function references.  Are the lists the only other thing in your program besides the function?

Comment: Also, when I called the function, I used the syntax `print(howareyou("Hi bot!"))` because since the function returns the random list elements instead of printing them, not all of the bot's responses will be displayed if you don't call the function inside a `print` statement.  How are you calling the function in your program?